# how to extract <code> content from html using scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy, selector

I inspect the following content that I want to extract.

```
<code style="display: none" id="bpr-guid-1441788">
  {"companyDetails":{"com.linkedin.voyager.jobs.JobPostingCompany":{"companyResolutionResult":{"entityUrn":"urn:li:fs_normalized_company:166973","name":"World Wildlife Fund","logo":{"image":{"com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorImage":{"id":"/p/3/000/093/367/1651958.png"}},"type":"LOGO_LEGACY"}},"company":"urn:li:fs_normalized_company:166973"}},"entityUrn":"urn:li:fs_normalized_jobPosting:324588733","formattedLocation":"Bozeman, Montana","jobState":"LISTED","description":{"attributes":[{"start":572,"length":1,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.LineBreak":{}}},{"start":0,"length":574,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph":{}}},{"start":574,"length":1,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.LineBreak":{}}},{"start":574,"length":2,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph":{}}},{"start":576,"length":18,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph":{}}},{"start":594,"length":316,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem":{}}},{"start":910,"length":134,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem":{}}},{"start":1044,"length":160,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem":{}}},{"start":1204,"length":342,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem":{}}},{"start":1546,"length":270,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem":{}}},{"start":594,"length":1222,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.List":{"ordered":false}}},{"start":1817,"length":1,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.LineBreak":{}}},{"start":1834,"length":1,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph":{}}},{"start":1835,"length":147,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem":{}}},{"start":1982,"length":129,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem":{}}},{"start":2111,"length":130,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem":{}}},{"start":2241,"length":92,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem":{}}},{"start":2333,"length":189,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem":{}}},{"start":1835,"length":687,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.List":{"ordered":false}}},{"start":2522,"length":1,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.LineBreak":{}}},{"start":2522,"length":1,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Bold":{}}},{"start":2522,"length":2,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph":{}}},{"start":2524,"length":12,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Bold":{}}},{"start":2524,"length":66,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph":{}}},{"start":2590,"length":1,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.LineBreak":{}}},{"start":2590,"length":1,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Bold":{}}},{"start":2590,"length":2,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph":{}}},{"start":2592,"length":9,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Bold":{}}},{"start":2592,"length":10,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph":{}}},{"start":2602,"length":17,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Bold":{}}},{"start":2619,"length":12,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Bold":{}}},{"start":2631,"length":78,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Bold":{}}},{"start":2602,"length":108,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem":{}}},{"start":2710,"length":88,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Bold":{}}},{"start":2710,"length":89,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.ListItem":{}}},{"start":2602,"length":197,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.List":{"ordered":false}}},{"start":2799,"length":177,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Bold":{}}},{"start":2799,"length":177,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph":{}}},{"start":2976,"length":0,"type":{"com.linkedin.pemberly.text.Paragraph":{}}}],"text":"World Wildlife Fund (WWF), the world’s leading conservation organization,&nbsp;seeks a Data Analyst.&nbsp;&nbsp;Under the direction of the supervisor, this position is responsible for providing data synthesis and analysis for the Northern Great Plains (NGP). S/he will assist the NGP program in communicating its goals and successes through the development of data synthesis products and developing statistical interpretation of existing and new datasets, with a focus on informing grassland conservation. S/he will develop products to disseminate information to NGP staff and partners. \n \n  Responsibilities Provide data synthesis and interpretation for existing and new datasets to support grassland conservation goals. Work with existing datasets to develop new ways of interpreting the data and communicating it to partners. Work with new datasets to help answer key science questions as outlined by the Program Manager. Given the list of science priorities for the program, develop methods for answering pressing questions using the best available data. Develop spatial data for use in projects. Collect and process datasets for use by NGP staff and partners, as needed and in partnership with the GIS Specialist. Support NGP Program by developing in-depth knowledge of grassland conservation and researching and developing skills in other approaches necessary to ensure success of WWF’s conservation strategies in the region. Build knowledge through research to keep up to date with the state of the art knowledge and apply the knowledge to WWF projects. The candidate will report to the Program Manager. S/he will also maintain strong relationships with the Managing Director, Deputy Director, NGO partner organizations, federal, state and provincial agency planning personnel and corporate and foundations staff at WWF-US.  \n  Qualifications A Master of Science Degree in Biostatistics, Biology, Conservation Biology, Zoology, Ecology, Wildlife Management, or a related field, is required 4+ years of experience in spatial analysis and data synthesis is required. A PhD will substitute for 3 years of work experience. Substantial and demonstrated experience in spatial analysis; data synthesis; and managing an independent work program is required Experience in biodiversity conservation and grassland-focused spatial datasets is preferred Candidates should have a strong commitment to the mission, goals, and values of WWF, good interpersonal and relationship-building skills, energy and enthusiasm, and high ethical standards. \n Please Note:&nbsp;This is a 2-year position based in Bozeman, Montana. \n To Apply: Please visit our&nbsp;Careers Page,&nbsp;job#17065, to submit an online application including resume and cover letter Due to the high volume of applications we are not able to respond to inquiries via phone As an EOE/AA employer, WWF will not discriminate in its employment practices due to an applicant’s race, color, religion, sex, national origin, and veteran or disability status."},"applyMethod":{"com.linkedin.voyager.jobs.OffsiteApply":{"applyStartersPreferenceVoid":true,"companyApplyUrl":"https://careers-wwfus.icims.com/jobs/1727/data-analyst---17065/job"}},"title":"Data Analyst","listedAt":1496950791000}
</code>
```

I tried several different ways to extract the content, especially the longest text part, such as

```
body.xpath('//code[@id="bpr-guid-1441788"]/text()').extract()
```

But there is no response, the return of scrapy is null.
Anyone can help me out?

Comment: Can you provide the url you are tying to crawl? It may be that the content is dynamically generated.

Comment: Try `body.xpath('//code[starts-with(@id, "bpr-guid-")]/text()').extract()`

Comment: @rongon, the link is : https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/324588733/?recommendedFlavor=HIDDEN_GEM&refId=2012397431497144675904&trk=d_flagship3_search_srp_jobs . I believe it is generated dynamically because the source code is different if you login. I tried to solve the problem with selenium and phantomJS.